# How to pass Components into a react-router Route using Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

When I pass in some Components to a `Route` Component I get a TS compiler error:

> Type '{ main: typeof MainComponent; sidebar: typeof SidebarComponent; }' is not assignable to type 'RouteComponents'.
>   Property 'sidebar' is incompatible with index signature.
>       Type 'typeof SidebarComponent' is not assignable to type 'ReactType'.
>         Type 'typeof SidebarComponent' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent'.
>           Type 'typeof SidebarComponent' provides no match for the signature '(props: any, context?: any): ReactElement'

I've tried to correctly construct a `RouteComponents` object, but I had to modify the `react-router`'s `index.d.ts` to export the `RouteComponents` definition as only `RouteComponent` is exported, and it still didn't like the expression. Where can I find out what a `RouteComponents` object supposed to look like?

Here is the simple file `routes.tsx`:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { IndexRoute, Route } from 'react-router'

import App from './components/App'
import MainComponent from './components/MainComponent'
import OtherMainComponent from './components/OtherMainComponent'
import SidebarComponent from './components/SidebarComponent'

const routes = () => {
  return (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute components={{ main: MainComponent, sidebar: SidebarComponent }} />
      <Route path="/add" components={{ main: OtherMainComponent, sidebar: SidebarComponent }} />
    </Route>
  )
}

export default routes
```

As I mentioned, I tried it the following way too:

```
const indexRouteComponents: RouteComponents = {
  main: MainComponent,
  sidebar: SidebarComponent 
}

const routes = () => {
  return (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute components={indexRouteComponents} />
      <Route path="/add" components={{ main: OtherMainComponent, sidebar: SidebarComponent }} />
    </Route>
  )
}
```

The `components={indexRouteComponents}` part does not have an error, but creating the `indexRouteComponents` object is an error (The same error as above, because it's not a correct `RouteComponents` object)

What is the correct way to set up the `react-router` Components using Typescript?

Edit: here are Github issues related to this:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4317
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/13689

Comment: I tried your code and I am having no issues. Using typescript 2.0. I just replaced the `RouteComponents` with `{ [key: string]: React.ReactType }` since the two are the same thing. Which version of typescript react are you using?

Comment: I can't use `{ [key: string]: React.ReactType }` here either. It gives the error: Type '{ main: typeof MainComponent; sidebar: typeof SidebarComponent; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: ReactType; }'. The Components extend from ReactComponent.

Comment: I am using Typescript 2.1.4, React 15.4.1, react-router 3.0.0, @types/react-router 2.0.41 (Do type definitions follow the same version numbering as the package it represents? Maybe my definitions are out of date)

Comment: You ever find an answer?

Comment: @CleverHuman I don't remember, but I did either work around it or solve it. I updated the question with the GitHub issues I created about it

Answer (score 1):

```
const AppRouter = [
{
    main: MainComponent,
    exact: true,
    path: "/",
    sidebar: SidebarComponent,
},
{
    main: OtherMainComponent,
    exact: true,
    path: "/add",
    sidebar: SidebarComponent,
}
```

];

And in your main component:

```
public render() {
    return (
        <Router>
           <div className={"sidebar"}> 
               {AppRouter.map((route, index) => (
                <Route
                    key={index}
                    path={route.path}
                    exact={route.exact}
                    component={route.sidebar}
                />
            ))}
            </div>
            <div className={"content"}>
                {AppRouter.map((route, index) => (
                <Route
                    key={index}
                    path={route.path}
                    exact={route.exact}
                    component={route.main}
                />
            ))}
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}
```